# How do I bridge a wifi connection from MacOS

Tags: macos, wifi, bootcamp, sharing

[I have used WiFi bridging in Windows 10 to share my WiFi with other devices. This was done on my Mac using Windows 10 on Bootcamp.  Specifically, I want to share WiFi to WiFi.

**How can I achieve the same on macOS?**

Here's what I'm seeing in Internet Sharing:

[image: edi]

Comment: It's called Internet Sharing.  Go to *Preferences → Sharing → Internet Sharing*  Let us know if that works or not.

Comment: That's not correct.  Internet Sharing works on Bluetooth, WiFi, Ethernet, even Thunderbolt.  If you have it on Windows 10, it should be there in macOS.  Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: Take the picture, edit it in Preview if necessary, then edit your question and click the "image" icon to upload/paste the file.

Comment: WiFi 2?  Did you create a network alias or do you actually have to WiFi adapters?

Comment: Affect?  No.  Confuses people not familiar with your changes?  Yes.  However, WiFi to WiFi is not impossible, you have to do this manually.  I'll have to research because this isn't something I would do because you'd immediately cut the bandwidth in half serving as both a WAP and a gateway.

Comment: Also, why would you do this?  If your devices have WiFi to begin with, just connect them to the WiFi and be done.

Answer (score 4):

I assume your question is how to share the WiFi internet connection you have with other devices on a cabled network.

You do this by opening System Prefences > Sharing and selecting Internet Sharing:

For "Share your connection from" choose "Wi-Fi".

For "To computers using" select the network that you want to share it with - usually this is "Ethernet".

This achieves connection sharing by using NAT.

If you actually want to bridge your WiFi connection with a cabled connection, so that devices on your cabled connection would work like they were connected directly to the WiFi, it can be achieved like this:

Open System Preferences > Network.

Click the cog wheel below the device list and select "Manage Virtual Interfaces".

Click the plus button and select "New Bridge".

Select "Wi-Fi" and the network you want to share it with - usually this is "Ethernet".

Click Create.

Comment: @A68AGaming Do you have 2 WiFi interfaces? (i.e. is this a laptop with built-in WiFi with an added WiFi-over-USB adapter or something like that?)

Comment: What are your options exactly when trying to create the new bridge? (i.e. which networks are shown)

Comment: You've added a photo for internet connection sharing earlier... that's not what I asked about?

Comment: Follow the steps in the second method I gave. Not the Internet Connection Sharing one.

Comment: I wanted you to take a screenshot? - I.e. click the plus button, select "New Bridge" - now take a screenshot of the window that comes up.

Comment: Did you disable Internet Connection Sharing before trying to make the Bridge? - Is it correct that you have a network named "Wi-Fi" and one named "Wi-Fi 2"

Comment: This answer does not work because "Wi-Fi" doesn't appear in the connections to bridge and that's by design according to https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/bridge-virtual-network-interfaces-on-mac-mh43557/mac.

Comment: @JasonR.Coombs This answer was written before the question was changed into specifying that it was WiFi to WiFi - that's why.