# Mac OSX Internet sharing settings - DHCP expectations

Tags: macos, network, settings, system-settings

I have a MacBook Pro running OSX 12.3.1. Monterey.

I'm trying to connect to a widget that has a web service running on it.

When I connect the widget directly to a normal residential Router, it receives ANY IP address (DHCP) successfully; I can ping it and make a successful http request.

When I connect the widget to the MBP, I can't figure out what IP it received.  It appears to be 192.168.2.2... I can ping this IP successfully, but the http request fails (server not found).

When Sharing the Internet connection on the Mac (wifi) to a widget (usb-c dongle plus an ethernet cable), this is what I think that I see:

| ROUTER | MacBook Pro | Widget |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10.0.1.1 | < - - 10.0.1.101 wifi |  |
|  | 192.168.2.1 eth - - > | 192.168.2.2 (?) eth |

My Widgets are old and can't be reconfigured, and fallback to an IP of 192.168.237.227 if they can't obtain a DHCP IP.

When I connect one of these widgets thru the MBP, I see this in using arp -a

> Spudbox19:~ tjt$ arp -a
> ? (10.0.1.1) at 44:a5:6e:4d:b4:ae on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
> ? (10.0.1.99) at 44:a5:6e:4a:83:92 on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
> ? (10.0.1.154) at ae:83:76:b7:e1:36 on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
> ? (10.0.1.155) at f0:b3:ec:6d:9f:53 on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
> ? (10.37.129.2) at 3e:22:fb:e:ad:64 on bridge100 ifscope permanent [bridge]
> **? (169.254.118.57) at ae:83:76:b7:e1:36 on en0 [ethernet]
>
> ? (169.254.244.255) at (incomplete) on en0 [ethernet]
>
> ? (192.168.2.2) at 0:60:35:9:6d:ae on bridge102 ifscope [bridge]**
>
> ? (224.0.0.251) at 1:0:5e:0:0:fb on en0 ifscope permanent [ethernet]
> ? (224.0.0.251) at 1:0:5e:0:0:fb on bridge100 ifscope permanent [ethernet]
> ? (224.0.0.252) at 1:0:5e:0:0:fc on en0 ifscope permanent [ethernet]
> ? (239.255.255.250) at 1:0:5e:7f:ff:fa on en0 ifscope permanent [ethernet]

The widget is correctly identified with Mac address ending in 6d:ae in the table.

ping 192.168.2.2 responds, but http://192.168.2.2 doesn't respond

How can I confidently determine the IP that the MBP issued to the Widget?

Is it possible configure the MBP to passthru (allow the widget to obtain an IP from the Router)?

How can I reach the Widget from the MBP (what IP should I be using to ping and make http requests)?

I tried setting the MBP ethernet port to specific Manual IP and DNS, seems to have no effect (it continues to issue 192.168.2.2 to its client, even if I specify Manual IP 10.0.2.1 and DNS 10.0.2.1)

Finally, what and why are there (2) 169.254 IPs in the arp?

Answer (score 1):

Internet sharing from Wi-Fi to Ethernet using macOS is accomplished by the Mac acting as a router to create a new LAN accessible from the Ethernet port. Since this Mac router uses NAT without port forwarding capabilities, the IP address assign to a device inside the new LAN can not be used by devices outside the new LAN to establish a connection. I was able to confirm that an iMac (21.5-inch, Late 2013), booted to either macOS 10.15.7 (Catalina) or macOS 10.13.6 (High Sierra), can reach http websites on the new LAN. Your MacBook Pro should have been able to reach a website hosted by a properly configured Widget on the new LAN. Otherwise, macOS 12.3.1 (Monterey) has a bug that did not exist in earlier macOS releases.

The `arp -a` command does identify any IP addresses assigned by the Mac to devices in the new LAN. The `169.254` IPs appearing in your `arp -a` listing may be currently unused entries. You might try entering `sudo arp -ad` to delete all entries before entering `arp -a`.

It is possible configure a Mac to pass thru (allow the widget to obtain an IP from the router). However, this at least depends on the version of macOS (OS X) and may depend on the Mac model. I tested using a iMac (21.5-inch, Late 2013) and macOS 10.15.7 (Catalina). The instructions are given in [jksoegaard's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/388562/how-do-i-bridge-a-wifi-connection-from-macos/388563#388563) to the question *"[How do I bridge a wifi connection from MacOS](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/388562/how-do-i-bridge-a-wifi-connection-from-macos)"* and the Apple website *"[Bridge virtual network interfaces on Mac](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/bridge-virtual-network-interfaces-on-mac-mh43557/12.0/mac/12.0)"*. Below are a few addition points to be added.

- Creating the Bridge interface removes any corresponding Ethernet interface and Wi-Fi interface. This means the Mac losses Wi-Fi internet access.
- While this worked under macOS 10.15.7 (Catalina), the same procedure failed to work properly properly under macOS 10.13.6 (High Sierra).
- If you remove the Bridge interface, any Ethernet and Wi-Fi interfaces, that were removed when the bridge was created, need to be added back in.